# How to add a column to _prepareColumns() that is not present in the database

Tags: magento-1.6, reports

How do I create a value then add it to the _prepareColumns() function?

I would like to work out a value then add it to a row that is coming form the database.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean that you want to take a value from field X off the table, manipulate it, and render it into column C?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do

Comment: ok - in that case, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

In `_prepareColumns` for your desired "dynamic column," try this:

```
$this->addColumn('my_column', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('My Column'),
    'type'      => 'text',
    'renderer'  => 'module/adminhtml_column_renderer_mycolumn'
));
```

Notice the `renderer` element, which points to an admin block (a column renderer). Construct your renderer like this:

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Column_Renderer_Mycolumn 
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract 
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row) 
    {
        // $row is your model
        return $row->getEnabled() ? '<strong>ENABLED</strong>' : '<em>DISABLED</em>';
    }

}
```